# MS Access VBA to update a Combobox table field

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a table with a field with the display control set to Combo Box and I have not been able to read or write to it using an OpenRecordSet.  What would I have to do to modify to get these scenarios to work?

```
Sub TryToRead()
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl", dbOpenDynaset)
x = rs!FieldName '<------Combo Box Field. x shows no info.
End Sub

Sub TryToWrite()

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl", dbOpenDynaset)
With rs
.AddNew
rs!FieldName = "Test Value" '<------ Results in Run-time error 64224 Application-defined or object-defined error
   .Update
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Advise not to build lookups in table. However, that should not prevent reading and writing values unless this is set up as a multi-value field. The error message is too generic to be helpful. Did you Google the message? Try an SQL INSERT action instead of opening recordset.

Comment: Allow Multiple Values is set to 'Yes' on this field.  Does that setting eliminate the capability of interacting with the values through VBA?

Comment: It certainly complicates VBA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/manipulate-multivalued-fields-with-dao. Research MVF, get a full understanding of them. I advise not to use Multi-value field which is an Access-exclusive feature.

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking at this link.  It seems to get me part of the way to what I would like to accomplish; however, I have not been able to effectively toggle the check boxes to switch them on/off.

Comment: Can't use VBA to 'toggle' checkboxes of an MVF combobox, period. It should reflect values saved into MVF.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have what I need.

```
Sub Testing()

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl", dbOpenDynaset)
MyStr = Array("Value1", "Value2")

Do Until rs.EOF = True
    Set rs2 = rs!FieldName!Value
    rs.Edit
    For Each c In MyStr
        rs2.AddNew
        rs2!Value.Value = c
        rs2.Update
    Next c
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Read and use [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/13935/option-explicit) and value is a bad name for field (needs praefix e.g. FieldValue)